# PHPmyadmin and Joomla with images field

Tags: mysql, image, joomla

I look to reorganize my images folder for Joomla web site.
All pictures in post are put under "Images and Links" as Intro images and Full Article Image
I try to made find and replace so for images field.
Images field are like this:
{"image_intro":"images/lavoceprima/1601/47369.jpg","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"", "image_fulltext":"images/lavoceprima/1601/47369.jpg","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}

So in find and replace of phpmyadmin I put 
Find: images/lavoceprima/16
Replace with: images/lavoceprima/2016/16
Column: images

I also try this below as / is strange for me
Find: images/lavoceprima/16
Replace with: images/lavoceprima/2016/16
Column: images

Nothing find. I made lot of other change in introtext field without problem but here nothing happens
Any help?

Btw I have more of 10.000 post on web so made manually is not solution :)
Joomla is 3.4.8 and phpmyadmin 4.3.8

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear from your post what you are doing, but this is what you should do - In the sql-tab in phpmyadmin, do:

```
update #__content set images=
replace(images, 'images/lavoceprima/16', 'images/lavoceprima/2016/16');
```

...where you replace #_ with your table prefix

Comment: Thanks for replay. I try it but not work. Or better not receive any wrong msg, but nothing change in images field. All stay like before this replace